# Python install failed windows 8.1- Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package

Tags: python, windows-8.1

I have windows 8.1 and tried installing: python-3.5.0rc3-amd64

I tried running as admin to no avail.

Here is the log of the failed install: http://pastebin.com/Y465P6zi.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2906956

Comment: I just installed all the latest windows updates including the one you linked to and still get the exact same failure.

http://pastebin.com/jQ7ETa40

Comment: Ok it worked when I tried with the .msi installer.

Comment: Reference to bug tracker issue: http://bugs.python.org/issue25157

Comment: @programminglearner, was a solution found, same problem here

Answer (score 12):

Manually install the Universal C Runtime update from Microsoft:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226

and then re-attempt installation of Python 3.5.

Comment: This worked! The runtime requires all windows updates to be current as well.

Comment: I am unable to install the universal C runtime manually. All versions of it tell me that the update is not applicable to my computer. I'm running a fresh install of 8.1 pro and using amd64.
---
Note: I had a few failed installs through `scoop install python`. This could have affected things.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson Same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Caelum No, however I was able to install an earlier version of python (3.4). I've swapped to debian8 since then to use python3.5

Comment: Does the problem have some relationship with Windows key?

Answer (score 9):

I too had the same issue. Try installing **Python 3.4.3**. It worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me _(and I'm grateful for the answer)_, although it's more of an alternative to the problem rather than a full solution.

Answer (score 3):

You may try some older version. I had similar issues and I tried a lot to update but not succeed. Then I tried for python-3.4.3. It's works fine for me. There are not much different between 3.4.3 and 3.5.0.

Answer (score 1):

Please update the window version from windows update(if you have blocked auto windows update).
This problem have nothing to do with product key.

Installing older version might help but, won't solve the purpose of installing the 3.5.X version

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I was trying to install Python on a computer that had its Windows Updates downloaded, yet not yet installed and configured.

Solution: reboot your computer so that all Windows updates are installed and configured, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Download python-2.7.14 following link:

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2714/

Install "python-2.7.14" and set PATH variable manual in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Create a New folder in the root of windows drive -> windows ( for example C:\windows\ ) and name it "installer", it's done. install again. it worked for me.